# JSON разобрать в модель

Tags: ios, json, objective-c

Здравствуйте. Делаю тестовое задание и возник вопрос.

Суть такова: делаю запрос на сервер, получаю в ответ JSON строку и затем кормлю ее в [библиотеку JSONModel](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel).

На нормальных примерах все отлично, но в одном ответе есть поле, которое без значений возвращает false:

```
"names":false
```

с одним строку:

```
"names":"Vasiliy"
```

а с несколькими массив:

```
"names":["Vasiliy", "Petr"]
```

И получаю в итоге ошибку

> Invalid JSON data. The JSON type mismatches the expected type...

В модели это поле

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray <Optional> *names;
```

Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: проверять что пришло, прежде чем загонять в переменную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по примерам, прилагаемым к библиотеке JSONModel, можно попробовать реализовать собственные методы для установления значений свойств модели. Насколько я знаю, объединить все возможные значения поля `names` различных типов в одном свойстве не получится, поэтому Вам придётся создать 3 отдельных свойства, которые можно объединить в отдельный класс. Выглядеть это может следующим образом:

```
@interface Names : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* names_string;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* names_bool;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* names_array;
@end
```

Предположим, что Ваш класс модели выглядит следующим образом:

```
@interface MyModel : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic) Names* names;
@end
```

Добавьте реализацию следующих методов:

```
@implementation Names

@end

@implementation MyModel

- (void)setNamesWithNSString:(NSString *)string {
    self.names = [[Names alloc] init];
    self.names.names_string = string;
}

- (void)setNamesWithNSArray:(NSArray *)array {
    self.names = [[Names alloc] init];
    self.names.names_array = array;
}

- (void)setNamesWithNSNumber:(NSNumber *)boolValue {
    self.names = [[Names alloc] init];
    self.names.names_bool = boolValue;
}

@end
```

Теперь после создания объекта Вашей модели проверяйте, какое из свойств (names_bool, names_array или names_string) было проинициализировано.